# Best practice for client/server communication Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, client-server

In starting activity I create and call a Thread:

```
new Thread (new Connect()).start();

Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //check if connected!
            while (!Connect.logged) {//logged is boolean
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
};
t.start();
```

In class Connect (implements Runnable) I create and open a socket. Besides method run, I also have methods sendMessage(String) and receiveMessage(), that use BufferOutputStream and BufferInputStream to communicate with server.

Now, I need to send and receive messages from other Activities. Is it good practice to make these methods static?

So I could call them, for example Connect.sendMessage("OK");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules to make a method static in Java

There is no hard and fast, well written rules, to decide when to make a method static or not, But there are few observations based upon experience, which not only help to make a method static but also teaches when to use static method in Java. You should consider making a method static in Java :

1) If a method doesn't modify state of object, or not using any instance variables.

2) You want to call method without creating instance of that class.

3) A method is good candidate of being static, if it only work on arguments provided to it e.g. public int factorial(int number){}, this method only operate on number provided as argument.

4) Utility methods are also good candidate of being static e.g. StringUtils.isEmpty(String text), this a utility method to check if a String is empty or not.

5) If function of method will remain static across class hierarchy e.g. equals() method is not a good candidate of making static because every Class can redefine equality.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/07/when-to-make-method-static-in-java.html#ixzz48L2fehQq